# Kotlin's Array vs ArrayList vs List for storing large amounts of data

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I'm building a *Deep Neural Network* in **Kotlin** (I know **Python** would be better, but I have to do that in Kotlin).

For training the net I need a huge amount of data from the [MNIST database](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/), this means I need to read about **60,000** images from a single file in IDX format and store them for simultaneous use.

Every image consists of 784 Bytes. So the total size is:
784*60,000 = 47,040,000 = ~47 MB of training data.
Which ain't that much, since I'm running the JVM in an 8GB RAM env.

After reading an image i need to convert it to a `KMatrix`, a custom data structure for matrix math operations. Under the hood of a `KMatrix` there's an `Array<Array<Double>>`.

I need a structure to store all the images at once, so I'm currently using a `List<KMatrix>`, which basically tranlates to a `List<Array<Array<Double>>>`

The problem is that while building the `List<KMatrix>` the Garbage Collector runs out of memory, launching a `OutOfMemoryException: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

I wonder if the problem is *which* data structures I'm using (i.e. should I use an ArrayList instead of an Array?) or maybe *how* I'm building the entire thing up (i.e. I need some optimization work to do).

I'll put the code, if needed, as soon as I can.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'll get a huge savings in memory and performance by replacing `Array<Array<Double>>` with `Array<DoubleArray>`. To take it a step further, you can use a 1D `DoubleArray` and get your elements using `[row * width + column]`. And to go even further, you might consider using a `DoubleBuffer` instead of a `DoubleArray`.

Comment: I think that's precisely what I was looking for. Great thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding the DoubleBuffer, you'd want to use `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8 * size).asDoubleBuffer()` instead of `DoubleBuffer.allocate(size)`. Direct buffers perform better.

Comment: Converting `Array<Double>` → `DoubleArray` is almost always worth it, as the latter stores the values as primitives, avoiding all the boxed `Double` objects that the former needs.  (Similarly for the other primitive array types.)  — However, converting an array of those into a single array with manual indexing would give a far smaller saving, and would be much less likely to justify the additional complexity.

Comment: @gidds yeah you're probably right but since in deep learning saving every millisecond is worth it, I'm trying to implement it anyway. Also, in my specific case turns out that there are some operations that are quite simpler with 1D DoubleArray - such as applying any given (Double) -> (Double) lambda to each element of the KMatrix. This is not a huge improvement but still it's a double win.

Comment: I also tried with DoubleBuffers, but it seems that they haven't got a direct set method and I totally need it for the implementations of some methods

Comment: @MicheleParadiso If it works in your case, then great!  I was also thinking of Posterity (i.e. other folk seeing this question in future).  (Though I guess they'd be more likely to find all this if it were in answers rather than comments…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-answer with the summarized solution (Thanks to answers by @Tenfour04 and @gidds)

As @Tenfour04 stated, you have basically three alternatives to the `Array<Array<Double>>` for the `KMatrix`:

1. an `Array<DoubleArray>` which mantains the same logic as the original, but saving lots of memory and increasing performance;
2. a 1-Dimensional `DoubleArray` which saves a bit of extra memory and performance, but with increased complexity given by the index-mapping of the array (the [i;j] element of the matrix is given by the [i * w + j] element of the array), and this probably isn't worth it as @gidds pointed out;
3. a 1-D `DoubleBuffer` created with `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8 * size).asDoubleBuffer()`, which improves performances even further but has only `get` and `put` methods, so it is useless if you need simple and direct set operations.

**Conclusion**
I choose the option 2, since in my case I'm performing very intensive operations, but in common cases, probably option 1 is the best as it is balanced in complexity and performance.
If you *need* a highest-performance structure and read/put methods are enough, I'd say that option 3 is what you're looking for.

Hope this helps someone